# Convert numeric offset to a timezone?

Tags: python, date, datetime, timezone, pytz

There is a website that provides timezone information in the form of e.g. `-07:00`. Is there a way I can use this to localize a timestamp in `pytz`?

Normally I am doing this:

```
EASTERN_TIMEZONE = pytz.timezone("US/Eastern")
date_in_pacific_time = EASTERN_TIMEZONE.localize(my_date)
```

where `my_date` is some datetime date. But I don't know how to take a number and get the timezone from it so I can apply it to the date and get a timestamp from it.

This may be an XY question though because what I want to do is take a date string like `"2021-04-02T18:30:04-07:00"` and convert it to a Unix UTC timestamp.

Edit:

Like this?

```
listing_date_string = "2021-04-02T18:30:04-07:00"
listing_date_string_datepart = listing_date_string[:19]
listing_date_string_timezone = int(listing_date_string[19:].replace(":00", ""))
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(listing_date_string_datepart, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
d -= datetime.timedelta(hours=listing_date_string_timezone)

print(int(d.timestamp()))  # outputs 1617427804
```

Comment: ISO Format: `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z`, so `%z` is what you need.

Comment: @Simon It doesn't seem to match, `ValueError: time data '2021-04-02T18:30:04-07:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'`

Comment: what is your python version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Python < 3.7*** - from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#technical-detail):

> Changed in version 3.7: When the %z directive is provided to the
> strptime() method, the UTC offsets can have a colon as a separator
> between hours, minutes and seconds.

Vice versa that means that with older Python versions, `%z` won't parse a UTC offset with a colon as hours/minutes separator. You can work around like

```
from datetime import datetime
# your input
s = "2021-04-02T18:30:04-07:00"
# parse separately, colon removed from UTC offset
tz = datetime.strptime(s[19:].replace(':', ''), '%z').tzinfo
dtobj = datetime.strptime(s[:19], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").replace(tzinfo=tz)
print(repr(dtobj))
```

```
datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 2, 18, 30, 4, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 61200)))
```

---

If you know the time zone, you can skip parsing the UTC offset:

```
import pytz
tz = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
dtobj = tz.localize(datetime.strptime(s[:19], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))
print(repr(dtobj))
```

```
datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 2, 18, 30, 4, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific' PDT-1 day, 17:00:00 DST>)
```

***Note: [`pytz` is deprecated](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/) with the release of Python 3.9 - you now have [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) in the standard lib.***

---

On ***Python 3.7+*** you can just use [fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat);

```
dtobj = datetime.fromisoformat(s)
```

and change from UTC offset to an actual time zone like

```
dtobj.astimezone(tz) # tz is a timezone object from pytz, dateutil, zoneinfo...
Out[9]: datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 2, 18, 30, 4, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific' PDT-1 day, 17:00:00 DST>)
```

Comment: pytz is no longer the correct way to address timezone in >2020, see discussions in https://bugs.launchpad.net/pytz/+bug/1884458 & https://github.com/stub42/pytz/issues/48. [`zoneinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html)  is the standard now (and on some systems that has no system wide time zone data like Windows, along with `tzdata` package), at least advise people to use `dateutil` instead.

Comment: @deadvoid: I am aware of the fact that one *should* use `zoneinfo` by now... But: I don't think that's the point of the question. And the OP is explicitly asking to use pytz. Keep in mind there is a lot of legacy code where you can't just replace pytz with zoneinfo. For Python <3.9 I'd suggest to use `dateutil` normally, because it follows the same semantics as zoneinfo.

Comment: well, there is [`backports.zoneinfo`](https://zoneinfo.readthedocs.io/en/latest) for older python version. Yes it's true that would means refactoring the legacy codes, but given the weight of people voicing their concern in those discussion links I think it's a worth while investment. Besides, I imagine it would be minimal change in most projects _and_ helps (at least a little) discouraging more people promoting `pytz`.

Answer (score 1):

For question X, it is not in general feasible.
But you have some candidate timezones in mind, like

- US/Pacific
- America/Phoenix
- US/Mountain (same as America/Denver)

so you could try each one to see if it matches -7 hours.

Some days Denver is at -7 hours,
on other days Los Angeles is at -7 hours.
And [Phoenix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Arizona#Daylight_saving_time) is at -7 hours *all the time*.

Note that a timezone, like US/Mountain, is quite different from a zone offset, like -7 hours.

For question Y, well, that's easy!
Just treat the first part as UTC,
then apply the remaining -7 hour correction.

Comment: Dumb question but does -7 mean "subtract 7 to reach UTC time" or "we are back 7 hours from UTC time, so add 7 to get there"?

Comment: -7 says a location is west of Greenwich, while +7 denotes locations east of Greenwich. High noon happens in London ~ seven hours before it happens in Phoenix. If your stamp is for 12 noon in Phoenix, add 7 to obtain 19:00 (7pm) in London.

Comment: I updated my OP, is that code snippet the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

does this work on your side?

```
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(
    "2021-04-02T18:30:04-07:00", 
    "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"
    )
```

```
print(
    dt.year,
    dt.month,
    dt.day,
    dt.hour,
    dt.minute,
    dt.second,
    dt.tzinfo,
    )
2021 4 2 18 30 4 UTC-07:00
```

Comment: No, `ValueError: time data '2021-04-02T18:30:04-07:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'`